# How can I understand the output of inxi -g?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Nvidia graphics card in my Ubuntu desktop, but it changes to `llvmpipe`. This is what is shown in my terminal running `inxi -G` command

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117GLM [Quadro T1000 Mobile] driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nouveau,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: N/A resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your actual question is just "How to fix this" but you haven't said what you want to fix. What OS & release are you using?  and details provided in the title should also exist in your question, as not all devices/browsers show the title text when your question is open & being read.   You can change *drivers* (ie. kernel modules) easily for LTS releases as you have choices; but you've not provided any release details thus we don't know what options you have available.

Comment: `llvmpipe` is used, when no suitable dedicated rendering tool was found. Have tried to install a proprietary nvidia driver? The available proprietary nvidia drivers depend on the version of Ubuntu, so if you want help, please tell us which version you are running (18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS or some other version)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)